# C++ how to add extra information to a field

Tags: c++, oop

I have a  class Student with a single integer variable

```
class Student {
 int id;...
};
```

Sometimes id refers to Students's id and sometimes it refers to an autogenerated
id that is completely unrelated to the student's id (maybe the student had no id
at all or did and was ignored). The problem is that when processing students algorithms have to vary their
behavior based on whether the id came with the student or it was autogenerated.

I was thinking of adding an extra field (a bool) to designate which is which.  But this
causes the danger of the two fields being out of sync.

Or have
an enum instead of a bool.  But I feel there must be a better way to designate this
in a more object oriented manner.

Comment: How about having two vectors of some sort, one for the auto generated id and one for the real id. Then have an int to keep them in sync (add the sum of the amount of id's). Just brain storming, I don't really know the purpose of your program.

Comment: Extra information is called using a different name.

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking of adding an extra field (a bool) to designate which is
>   which. But this causes the danger of the two fields being out of sync.

This is what data hiding is about.  If you make both fields private, you have control over keeping them in sync through public member functions, e.g.

```
class Student {
public:
    Student()
        :id_(rand()),
        autogen_(true)
    {}

    Student(int id)
        :id_(id),
        autogen_(false)
    {}

    void SetID(int id)
    {
        id_ = id;
        autogen_ = false;
    }

    int GetID() const { return id_; }
private:
    int id_;
    bool autogen_;
};
```

Comment: I also think information hiding could be the key oo idea here, but you didnt solve the setting and accessing of data here. The point of information hiding is not to let the user of the class be able to set autogenerated field themselves, but the implementation does it when setting the id, eliminating the out of sync data problem. And also very important, doing it right will augment the readability of your code, eliminating the need for comments.

Comment: @EmileVrijdags: See the default constructor.  I don't know what his exact specifications are, and I don't need to.  I gave him the important information that he needs to solve his problem, he can figure out how to apply it to his specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

If auto-generated numbers are only positive, you can add negative sign when you assigning student ids. This would let you differentiate between auto-generated and your assigned ids. And when using ids you can take absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for the enum - it makes code more readable than the bool and it will probably takeup as much memory as the bool anyway then you can expand it if you have a requirement to have a third kind of ID.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know or care much for OOP theory, but you can encode the information in the type.

```
// tagged_id<T1> and tagged_id<T2> are distinct types that convert to int
template <typename Tag>
struct tagged_id {
    int id;
    explicit tagged_id(int id) : id(id) {}
    operator int() const { return id; }
};

struct student {
    struct autogenerated_id;
    struct real_student_id;
    // variant is a tagged union of types — it'll either be one or the other
    boost::variant<tagged_id<autogenerated_id>, tagged_id<real_student_id>> id;
};
```

You can read [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) docs on how to act on the stored value.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you could use a "base student" class which defines the interface of how the processing algorithm handles student objects, and then have separate derived classes for each type of ID (student ID or auto-generated), each of which has appropriate processing handling logic defined in the derived class. This is a more object-oriented design.